# PWA offline-first, connection detection strategies

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to turn my react app into PWA with offline first approach where:

1. Static resources are cached using CacheAPI
2. Data is stored in IndexedDB

I want to cover specific case when user creates/updates/deletes data during the offline mode.

Scenario i have on mind is:

1. User opens app
2. Data is loaded from IndexedDB
3. User loses connection
4. User creates new entity
5. Connection comes back
6. Data should be sent to server

I am aware there is a Background Sync API but its browser support seems still very limited so i am wondering about 2 things:

1. What is the best mechanism for detecting connection going on/off?
2. Does this approach mean client generated guids for entities and keeping track locally of whats synced and whats not?

If someone could shed a bit of light on what is the usual architectural overview, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
//ON PAGELOAD  
  window.addEventListener('online', function (e) {
    this.IsOnline = true;
     this.employees = fetchFromLocalIndexDB();
     this.employees.forEach(function (item) {          
      if (item.FlagStatus == Status.Insert) {
         //CALL WEB API AND SEND TO REMOTE DATABASE
         myAPI.Post(url + item);
       });
      //GET ALL EMPLOYEES FROM THE REMOTE SQL DATABASE
        this.employees = myAPI.Get();

      //LOAD LOCAL DATABASE WITH EMPLOYEEES FROM THE REMOTE SQL DATABASE
        loadLocalDatabaseArray(this.employees);
      } 
    }, false);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [edit] your answer to add a bit more information about how this code work and why it will best solve the problem the OP is having. Thanks!